# How to extract specific word and store to a variable using grep

Tags: bash, grep

I want to ask about how to use grep to extract these bold words below :

Subject: [print][**printer-tj**]

From: John Smith <**john.s@gmail.com**>

To: print@gmail.com

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Content-Type: **application/pdf**; name="**a.pdf**"

For example I want to store those words to different variables :

```
a = printer-tj

b = john.s@gmail.com

c = application/pdf

d = a.pdf
```

How to realize it using grep?

As I know I can use like this but I'm not sure if this is correct :

```
a = grep -Po 'Subject: [print][\K[^]]+'
```

Comment: Elaborate **these bold words below** please.. The question is unsalvageable at the moment.Post an [\[ **mcve** \]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure what is your purpose storing all the variables as you need. But here goes my attempt:-

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(grep -w "Subject:" file | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g')

b=$(grep -w "From:" file | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' RS="<" FS=">")

c=$(grep -w "Content-Type:" file | awk 'NR>1{print}' | awk -F";" '{print $1}' | cut -d ":" -f2)

d=$(grep -w "Content-Type:" file | awk 'NR>1{print}' | awk -F";" '{gsub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}' | cut -d "=" -f2)
```

Will produce the output when `echo`'d to stdout.

```
printer-tj
john.s@gmail.com
application/pdf
a.pdf
```

Comment: Chaining `grep` and `awk` makes littles sense, as `awk` can do anything `grep` can. Chaining several invocations of `awk` is even worse.

Comment: Am just a beginner in `awk`, please provide more effective solutions applicable. I never implied mine was optimal.

Comment: Well, something like `awk 'NR>1{print}' | awk -F";" '{print $1}'` is equivalent to `awk -F";" 'NR>1{print $1}'`. You can replace any use of `cut` with a better `awk` field separator, and `grep` is the same as an `awk` pattern match.

Comment: The original post is unclear, so this may not be a solution, but it is an alternative to your suggestion: `BEGIN { FS="[\\[\\]<>\"; ]+" }
/^Subject:/ { a = $3; next; }
/^From:/ { b = $2; next; }
/^Content-Type:/ { c = $2; d = $4; next; }
END { print a, b, c, d; }`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually it  works for a and b, but for c and d it also print text/html for c and UTP-8 for d. How to remove text/html and UTP-8 ? @Inian

Comment: @user2290560: Works fine for me! Are you sure the contents are the same as you posted in the description.

Comment: @Inian: I'm sorry it works well now. For example I have multiple Content-type row so I just change NR> value based on my need. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a bit more concise:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[\\[\\]<>\"; ]+" }
/^Subject:/ { a = $3; next; }
/^From:/ { b = $4; next; }
/^Content-Type:/ { c = $2; d = $4; next; }
END { print a, b, c, d; }' file | read a b c d
```

Comment: When read a b c d is called, it does not show anything while it's ignored it will show as I want. So how can I use the result outside awk because I need a, b, c, d value for my next code. By the way, b will produce Smith not his email.

Comment: @user2290560 Ah, yes, that should have been `$4` for the email address. I have fixed it now. Of course, you have to take into account that the pipe creates a new subshell. So use `{ read a b c d; echo $a }`, or whatever.

Comment: Yeah it works now. However maybe this solution only for limited case. It does not work if From has different name (sometimes people's name have more than 3 words) and filename contain more words instead of one word (eg. not a.pdf but some example.pdf)

Comment: @user2290560 Well, as sjsam pointed out, your original question is very short on details.

Comment: I'm sorry but thanks for the answers. Now I have more knowledge on AWK script @Michael Vehrs

Comment: @user2290560 The gist of my solution is: don't use long, inefficient pipelines. Use a single command to generate the output you require.